# Type ERROR when upgrading to tensorflow 2.9

Tags: tensorflow, keras, types, upgrade

After upgrading to tensorflow 2.9 I got the following Erro message
when calling model.fit()
with tf 2.8 there were no error.
The fit runs anways but its worrying.

```
2022-06-21 12:42:58.930086: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_BOOL
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
    }
  }
}

    while inferring type of node 'calculate/cond/output/_10'
```

Any idea what can cause this or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post your code with the issue? Just the error message itself is a bit vague.

Comment: Please share some minimal reproducible code to understand this error.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cant really provide more information, since I got the message for the following code:                                                                                                                      self.train_model.fit(
                train_generator.get(),
                epochs=self.epochs,
                validation_data=val_generator.get(),
                callbacks=self.callbacks
            )                                                           I got the same message for different model architectures, so its hard to reduce the search space

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to tf.train, tf.io, or tf.data... I probably have to redo the code for saving TFRecords and loading them again. Hopefully it will be better because it takes a million years to save anything with the current code (developed on 2.2, upgraded to 2.4, now trying to upgrade to 2.9).

Comment: Did anyone find out the reason for this error?

Answer (score 4):

This should be a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation for that. I have seen the same type of error message appear in the output type of the tensorflow guide here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/evaluator and here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrating_feature_columns . You can easily find the lines with the error by searching for "type inference failed" after following the links.

Comment: It also shows up here: https://www.tensorflow.org/responsible_ai/fairness_indicators/tutorials/Fairness_Indicators_on_TF_Hub_Text_Embeddings

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, this seems to be still an open issue. For those who may read this in the future, keep an eye on the pertinent issues posted on [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/57052) and [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16978) repos. Although there has been [some pushback](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16978#issuecomment-1252685663) against the statements like *[...is just a warning, you can safely ignore it. Given code executed without any error message.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16978#issuecomment-1246418935)*, for now, one ***MAY*** want to ignore this warning as suggested by Keras Team:

> [I think this should be reproducible without involving any Keras logic, at which point the TF folks will definitely look at it. But anyway, as said before, this is just a warning, not something critical. You can ignore it.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16978#issuecomment-1277940281)